# Qt QSpinbox: accept only values of stepsize (16)

Tags: qt, qspinbox

I want to have a spinbox that allows only value in steps such as 0, 16, 32, ...
The problem is, that with each entered number the valueChanged signal emits and if I check the values for example by rounding to the next number

```
if (value % incrX != 0)
{
    value = round(value / incrX) * incrX;
    ui->spinBoxX->setValue(value);
    return;
}
```

This does not work, since I can not enter "12". The first "1" round to 0 and every futher value will result in 0 as well.

Any ideas? I could deaktivate the edit and leave only the up-down buttons. Or I could mark the text red if not valid and mark it normal if the value is valid.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Use QSpinBox::editingFinished, like this:

```
QSpinBox sb;
sb.setSingleStep(12);
QObject::connect(&sb, &QSpinBox::editingFinished, [&](){
   sb.setValue( sb.value() / sb.singleStep() * sb.singleStep() ) ; });
sb.show();
```

Or use delegate/validator to show and edit you specific behavior.